# Substitution of certain occurences of a string with another string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

Sorry if someone already posted the same question, but I was unable to find it.

I am trying to replace certain occurrences of a string pattern with something else. The problem I do not want to replace all occurrences, just all apart from one.

For example.
Imagine I have the string: `'(M:2,Seq0:2):10,Seq1:20,(Seq2:40,Seq3:40)'`
The pattern I want to find is: `'\w+\d+:\d'`  (which refer to `Seq[number]`)

Imagine I want to change all numbers after `'Seq[number]:'`
but not the one following for example, `'Seq1:'`

Imagine that to all these numbers after `Seq[number]:` I wanna sum the value of 10

in The end I would like to have the string:

```
'(M:2,Seq0:12):10,Seq1:20,(Seq2:50,Seq3:50)'
```

Is there a way of doing this in a loop?
I tried to use re.findall, but it returns all occurences in a text. How could I incorporate this in a loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `re.sub` with a function as the replacement, for example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '(M:2,Seq0:2):10,Seq1:20,(Seq2:40,Seq3:40)'
>>> def repl(match):
...     return match.group(1) + str(int(match.group(2)) + 10)
...
>>> re.sub(r'(\w+(?!1:)\d+:)(\d+)', repl, s)
'(M:2,Seq0:12):10,Seq1:20,(Seq2:50,Seq3:50)'
```

The restriction to not match `Seq1:` is handled by the negative lookahead `(?!1:)`, the capturing groups are used just to separate the portion of the string that you want to modify from the rest of it.  The replacement function then returns group 1 unchanged plus the value from group 2 plus 10.

As suggested by Cilyan in comments, you could also add the restriction to not replace for `Seq1:` in the replacement function, which simplifies the regex.  Here is how this would look:

```
def repl(match):
    if match.group(1) == 'Seq1:':
        return match.group(0)
    return match.group(1) + str(int(match.group(2)) + 10)

result = re.sub(r'(\w+\d+:)(\d+)', repl, s)
```

**edit:** To address the questions in your comment, here is how you could write this to modify the number that you add and which prefix (like Seq1:) should be ignored:

```
def make_repl(n, ignore):
    def repl(match):
        if match.group(1) == ignore:
            return match.group(0)
        return match.group(1) + str(int(match.group(2)) + n)
    return repl

result = re.sub(r'(\w+\d+:)(\d+)', make_repl(10, 'Seq1:'), s)
```

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to decide which Seq to substitute inside the function rather than using a lookahead, as the regex can get quite complicated if OP wants to filter out more than 1~2 sequences.

Comment: @Cilyan Good suggestion, added that to my answer.

Comment: I'm new to python. So why you don't pass an argument to 'repl' in 'result'? And If I want to pass arguments? For example, if I want to pass the number to sum as an argument? Both my number and Seq1 will change over time...

Comment: `repl` is kind of like a callback function, so for each match that the regex encounters the function provided (`repl` in this case) will be called with the match object as the only argument provided.  See my edit for how to modify the number and which prefix to ignore:

Comment: Thanks!! Reading in the internet... I also discovered the lambda... so if I write result = re.sub(pattern,lambda m: m.group(1)+str(int(m.group(2)) + number,s)? Where number would be a number I would pass on my loop. Would it be efficient? Or is it better to always write a function?

Comment: Yeah the method you described using a lambda would work fine and would be the same as a normal function definition for efficiency.